# Post dynamic fields and style

Tags: posts

dynm[image: Desired Post style]

I am stuck in getting wordpress post to the attached screnshot's style, My apology for being a pretty noobs amd my question shows it.
I searched and found a wonderful article : [how-to-display-word-count-of-wordpress-posts-without-a-plugin](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-display-word-count-of-wordpress-posts-without-a-plugin/)
Most of my desired features are figured out there very well but still looking for a way to input price field, can I have a price field while posting from admin panel ?

Comment: You can use Custom Field to add the price to a post. Then use the meta key to retrieve information for the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a custom field. On post or page edit page click **Screen Options** in the top right corner anb select *Custom Fields*. Add a Name and Value pair for example: price (for the name) and 9$ (for the value).

Then in your single.php or whatever template use this code to display it:

```
<?php echo "Price:" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", true); ?>
```

**Reference:**
[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Thank you very much Borek for this solution, it works as I want